# HTC One X won't charge

Tags: charging, htc-one-x

I bought a HTC one X in China, in order to send it to my girlfriend who's in UK, but she's constantly get charging problems.

The problem is like this:

1. Can't charge at all using AC adapter if the battery is not empty. The battery bar just keep decreasing no matter whether you plugged the power line or not. (Faster with the line plugged). The only way to get it charged is to wait until the phone drain its battery and die. Then it charges again.
2. Battery can be charged with computer USB, but very very S..L..O..W. Maybe after hours and you get an 1% increase.
3. When using 1) the battery bar is around 50% after one night's charge. Restarting or shutting down\start again from the Android GUI won't help. But if we shut-down the phone and restart using the HBoot, it will show a bar of nearly 100%.

My girlfriend didn't have the adapter shipped along with phone. She has a BlackBerry 5V600mA adapter and a 5V1A adapter bought from AMAZON. Neither of them work. We hesitate to use a 2A adapter because we fear it may do harm to the battery.

I have read a lot threads these days. I think its maybe caused by some error on battery software of system or hardware error. But others' problems didn't seem totally the same with mine, and the solutions to these problems didn't work.

Does anyone have idea to deal with it?

Comment: Did you buy an original HTC or a fake? I assume it's a hardware problem. If you've bought an original HTC you could go to a HTC store and get a replacement as long as it's will in its warranty period. Charging with a 2A adapter should be a problem actually. 2A means that it's capable of giving 2 amps to your device while the phone might ask just 0,6-0,9 amps.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the root cause. Quite a long time since I last visit this post. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had this problem with my HTC One X, I have used several adapters and all of them were charging as normal.

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but you could try to do a reset of your phone, to make sure it is not a software related problem. But I guess the problem will still remain after the reset, so in that case, it is pretty sure that it is a hardware related problem of your phone. So you might want to contact HTC support for this problem. I think the only solution will be to swap your defective device with a working one.

Answer (score 0):

original charger would solve all of your problems...
I had a similar problem on my hox as well, even with samsung galaxy s3 charger, everything is normal when I charge with original charger device & cable

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset to factory settings, charge with ant without SIM card, reeboot.